# Are bots different from crawlers from python Django point of view

Tags: python, django, web-crawler, scrapy, bots

Actually i am confused with the terminology. I am studying the scrapy and i think its for crawling the website and extract some data.

But i want to make some python programs which does something like the actual users does. I mean like automating tasks.

E,g Go to www.myblah.com and then get the cheapest product in some category and if that is less than my preset amount , then send me email.

Now i dont know whether these type of things come under crawling or something else.

Can i do that in scrapy or we have other libraries for doing those kind of tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) is framework that can be used to create a bot or a crawler (aka spider).  A crawler is specific kind of bot, but a bot isn't necessarily a crawler.  Crawlers are defined by being designed to explore the graph of pages (nodes) and their embedded URLs (edges) although they may be restricted from following particular URLs.

Automating tasks is the work of a bot.  Whether Scrapy will work for that will depend on what information is needed and how actions have to be taken.  Many sites are heavy on javascript these days, so if the bot can't execute javascript and correctly provide cookies it may not be able to get the information to it's task.  Some web automation tasks may require a browser plug-in or even GUI automation tools may be needed.